# Syncing and Mirroring data between 2 servers automatically cPanel

Tags: server, synchronization, centos7, replication, mirroring

I have two servers and both are working fine.

How to sync all my data from one server to another server/backup-storage/remote-storage.

I want to know if one of my server is down due to heavy load then how to use instantly second server and what is the role of DNS in this, because if we use another server then we have to change DNS also for particular website so how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check cloudflare load balancer.

Architecturally you have two problems to solve:

1. load balancing (how clients are routed to one of the servers) - this involves sometimes DNS settings but because cloudflare hosts your DNS as well, you are cool
2. Synchronization: files and database sync between hosting accounts. Now here there is no standard way to go especially because your are hosted using cpanel

**DATABASE:**
You can't use master-master or master-slabe database replication mechanisms like [Galera Cluster](https://galeracluster.com/) has.
You're best bet is to have a cron that will export the database from one server to the other. (using mysqldump - basically exporting and then importing)
on live:

```
mysqldump -u userName -p  yourLiveDatabaseName > live_database_export.sql
```

on the hot backup (your other account):

```
mysql -u username -p yourOtherServerDatabaseName < live_database_export.sql
```

**FILES:**
If you have SSH access use rsync.

Otherwise you may need to invent something.
For instance you can check the Cpanel API in regards to account transfers -> that will solve the database as well https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/whm/operation/create_remote_user_transfer_session/

As a remark - you are not in the best position to do HA having two cPanel shared accounts. What I usually do is to use virtual machines that are sync at the hypervisor level.